# Given that $ y = ax^2 + bx - a^2$ has gradient $ -4$ at $(-2, -13),$ find possible values for $a$ and $b$.

Tags: derivatives

Given that $y = ax^2 + bx - a^2$ has gradient $-4$ at $(-2, -13),$ find possible values for $a$ and $b.$

Could someone lay out the steps to solving this problem?

The book gives the answers as:

$a = 3, b = 8$

or

$a = -7, b = -32$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math correctly.

Comment: A reference for MathJax, to add onto manooooh's comment -- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y (x)= ax^2 + bx - a^2.$

We know that $y(-2)=-13$ and $y'(-2)=-4.$ From this we get two equations for $a$ and $b$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thanks Fred, this was all I needed! I knew I had to to get two equations but was going about it in strange ways and getting no closer to an answer.